# Unable to access arrays in cloud firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve an array from cloud firestore but when I log , it seems it is undefined.

This is my Cloud firestore structure.
[image: This is my Cloud fire store structure]

I am trying to get the array from the cloud firestore and store it in a variable in the ticket.component class

**ticket.component.ts**

```
export class TicketComponent {
    constructor( public cardService: CardService,private arrayService: ArrayService ) {  }

    //cards: Cardint[];

    ngOnInit()
    {

    }

    card : Cardint = this.arrayService.card;

    url: String =this.card.videolink;

    movieTitle ="";
    screen: string = "LUXE CINEMAS";
    time: string = "FRI, 6:45PM"

    rows: string[] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
    cols: number[]  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    reserved :string []= this.card.Reserved; 

    /*eg: reserved: string[] = ['A2', 'A3', 'F5', 'F1', 'F2','F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4']*/

    selected: string[] = [];

    ticketPrice: number = 120;
    convFee: number = 30;
    totalPrice: number = 0;
    currency: string = "Rs";

    //return status of each seat
    getStatus = function(seatPos: string) {
        console.log(this.reserved);
        if(this.reserved.indexOf(seatPos) !== -1) {
            return 'reserved';
        } else if(this.selected.indexOf(seatPos) !== -1) {
            return 'selected';
        }
    }

    //clear handler
    clearSelected = function() {
        this.selected = [];
    }

    //click handler
    seatClicked = function(seatPos: string) {
        console.log(this.reserved);
        var index = this.selected.indexOf(seatPos);

        if(index !== -1) {
            // seat already selected, remove
            this.selected.splice(index, 1)
        } else {
            //push to selected array only if it is not reserved
            if(this.reserved.indexOf(seatPos) === -1)
                this.selected.push(seatPos);
        }
    }

    //Buy button handler
    showSelected = function() {
        console.log(this.reserved);
        if(this.selected.length > 0) {
            alert("Selected Seats: " + this.selected + "\nTotal: "+(this.ticketPrice * this.selected.length + this.convFee));
        } else {
            alert("No seats selected!");
        }
    }

}
```

In cardservice I am getting the full collection of cards.

**cardservice.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Cardint} from '../service/cardint';
import { AngularFirestore ,AngularFirestoreCollection,AngularFirestoreDocument} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CardService {
    cards: Observable<Cardint []>
    cardCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Cardint>;
    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
        this.cards= this.afs.collection('cards').valueChanges();
    }

    getcards(){
        return this.cards;
    }

}
```

**arrayservice.ts**

```
export class ArrayService {

    card: any;

    constructor(){}

    doAnyThing()
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

**usercomponent.ts**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    cards: Cardint[];

    constructor(public auth: AuthService , private arrayService: ArrayService, public cardService: CardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cardService.getcards().subscribe( cards => {
            this.cards = cards;
        })
    }

    // u=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).email;
    book = 'BookNow'

    onUserClick(card)
    {
        this.arrayService.card = card;
    }

}
```

When user clicks on the particular card , I will send the particular card details to ticketcomponent using a service. The problem arrives here when I try to  access the array of particular card. It says that the variable is undefined.

Comment: Could you share your `array.service.ts`.

Comment: @Mikefox2k  sure, I have

Comment: this is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ticket.component.ts` you have this line of code:

```
reserved :string []= this.card.Reserved;
```

But if you check the screenshot of your firebase structure you can see that the field you are looking for is actually named `Registered`.

So it makes sense that you getting an `undefined`, since when you log `this.reserved` it will look for a value that does not exists on the firestore, and therefore, it will be undefined.

Change the previously mentioned line of code to the following, and it should work:

```
reserved :string []= this.card.Registered;
```

Comment: thank you, I know its a silly mistake but you took your time to help me. once again thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)